# C# Assigning a new value to a variable

Tags: c#

So I'm totally new to C#, in fact i just started learning the syntax about half an hour ago.

What i have done until now is just messing with the syntax and made an interactive input program of a few lines of code. When i was done typing my code and wanted to run the program, it gave me an error.

```
        Console.Write("What is your name?: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();    //'name' used here
        Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name);
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("How old are you?: ");
        int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("So you're name is " + name + " and you are " + age + " years old?");
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Tell me, yes or no?: ");
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();


        if (answer == "no" || answer == "No")

        { 
           Console.Write("Ahh okay, what was your name again?: ");
           string name  = Console.ReadLine();    //'name' used here
        }
```

"A local or parameter named 'name' cannot be declared in this scope ..."

I knew the problem had to be in the last line of code, where i assigned a new value to the string 'name'. I know for sure this is possible in PHP, assigning new values to variables. As i said im totally new to C# , i would like to know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: Just remove the `string` before the second `name  = Console.ReadLine();`.

Comment: You already have a variable called name!

Comment: Maybe a c# tutorial is a good starting point then: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Sharp-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners

Comment: are the double asterisk a paste error or need removed? ` **name**` change to simply `name``

Comment: Also, have a read about variables scope in C#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply that you cannot declare a variable twice. When you type `string name` you are declaring it. Try as follows:

```
    string name;
    Console.Write("What is your name?: ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name);
    Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("How old are you?: ");
    int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("So you're name is " + name + " and you are " + age + " years old?");
    Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Tell me, yes or no?: ");
    string answer = Console.ReadLine();


    if (answer == "no" || answer == "No")

    { 
       Console.Write("Ahh okay, what was your name again?: ");
       name  = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Haha, i knew it was something this simple. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

thats because you redeclared the variable name twice. just remove the string declaration. You can't define the same variable name also in sub scopes.  (between `{ }`)

```
   if (answer == "no" || answer == "No")

    { 
       Console.Write("Ahh okay, what was your name again?: ");
       name = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are declaring your string variable `name` at this line:

```
string **name** = Console.ReadLine();
```

Then, inside your `if` statement, you try to declare it again. If you mean to "reuse" the same variable, just remove the string portion (that tells c# you are declaring a variable of type string):

```
name = Console.ReadLine();
```

Have fun learning!

Answer (score 0):

name is already declared. To assign new value you don't need to specify type of variable. So remove `string` before `name` in last line.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "string" ?

```
    { 
       Console.Write("Ahh okay, what was your name again?: ");
       **name**  = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```